# Accessing type properties without "this" keyword in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this code snippet:

```
class Player implements OthelloPlayer {

    depth;

    constructor(depth: number) {        
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    getMove(state: OthelloState) {
        return this.MinimaxDecision(state, this.depth);
    }
}
```

I would like to call MinimaxDecision without the 'this' keyword. The goal is to avoid loosing the 'this' context to the window or another object - which happened quite often when calling the method from another class or function.

Comment: Just use an arrow function https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the `getMove` method to be a property that is assigned an arrow function to preserve the value of `this`:

```
class Player implements OthelloPlayer {
    constructor(public depth: number) {        
    }

    getMove = (state: OthelloState) => {
        return this.MinimaxDecision(state, this.depth);
    };
}
```

Sidenote: The above code will have a compile error because `MinimaxDecision` is not defined. You can define it however you would like.

Doing that ensures that the value of `this` inside `getMove` will be the instance of the class because it transpiles to this code (notice how `this` is stored then used in `getMove`):

```
var Player = (function () {
    function Player(depth) {
        var _this = this;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.getMove = function (state) {
            return _this.MinimaxDecision(state, _this.depth);
        };
    }
    return Player;
})();
```

If you don't want to use a property that's an arrow function, then instead of doing statements like this...

```
let player = new Player(10);
someObject.onClick = player.getMove;
```

...do...

```
let player = new Player(10);
someObject.onClick = () => player.getMove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot loose the 'this' for calling class members. What you can do is using [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) anywhere. They solve all 'this' issues.

For example:

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do so would be to use outside declaration of variable - it will work, but only for singleton (you are limited to use only one instance of class, because outside variable will be shared between instances).

```
let depth;
class Player implements OthelloPlayer {

    constructor(_depth: number) {        
        depth = _depth;
    }

    getMove(state: OthelloState) {
        return this.MinimaxDecision(state, depth);
    }
}
```

Beware, this solution is not only limited to singletons or static classes, but also can be considered as antipattern and bad practice by other developers ('cos it breaks encapsulation paradigm).

Another, more appropriate solution would be to use of destructuring assignment at start of the method:

```
class Player implements OthelloPlayer {
    
    depth;

    constructor(_depth: number) {        
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    getMove(state: OthelloState) {
        const { depth } = this; 

        return this.MinimaxDecision(state, depth);
    }
}
```

And most exotic solution would be to find/write own TS plugin which does what you want.